# Tela de Form de Login Fica Piscando

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, login

Estou com um problema: tenho uma tela de login que eu fiz, porém ela fica piscando. Não queria que isto acontecesse.

Queria que ficasse estático o form de login com as imagens passando em 5 em 5 minutos.

[image: tela de login]

No link não tem a caixa cinza.

Eu queria a caixa cinza também.

Aqui o link do problema: [Link do problema](https://weec-sistemas.000webhostapp.com/sistema-teste/login.php)

Comment: Sem o código fonte é difícil de ajudar. Mas acredito que isto esteja acontecendo porque o seu _slider_ foi colocado na tag *<body>!* Sugiro você criar uma _div_ que tome 100% de _width_ e _height_ e nela atribuir o slider! Assim, esse componente estará separado dos outros elementos do seu site! Isto está acontecendo porque quem está sendo alterado é o _body_, logo tudo dentro dele também é alterado!

Comment: Esta aqui o codigo: https://weec-sistemas.000webhostapp.com/sistema-teste/scripts.txt

Comment: Teria como me explicar?

Comment: Sobre piscar, reparei que quando a imagem não está no Cash ela demora alguns microsegundos para carregar pela primeira vez, depois que já carregou ela não pisca mais na transição

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece porque sua imagem esta sendo adicionada **"dinamicamente"** ao `documento`... em resumo ela não é carregada ao mesmo tempo em que o conteúdo da página é carregado.

Este "efeito" só acontece enquanto a imagem ainda não esta no **cache do navegador**, após cada imagem ser carregada as demais transições não terão este efeito na imagem já o formulário... como você esta aplicando a função `fadeOut()` e `fadeIn()` na classe que comporta o formulário logo o formulário também ele recebe este efeito.

Para contornar isto pode simplesmente substituir as funções **fade** por uma classe css com a propriedade `transition`.

Já sei slide esta configurado para acontecer a cada 5 segundos (5000) e não 5 minutos (300000 ou 1000 * 60 * 5).

Já a cor do `background` precisa ser definida:

O seguinte exemplo utiliza 10 segundos (10000) e um `background-color` `#d3d3d3` para o formulário além de usar a propriedade `transition` do css para promover a transição entre imagens ao invés de usar **fade**.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var count = 0;
  var images = [
      "https://weec-sistemas.000webhostapp.com/sistema-teste/img/bg-1.jpg",
      "https://weec-sistemas.000webhostapp.com/sistema-teste/img/bg-2.jpg",
      "https://weec-sistemas.000webhostapp.com/sistema-teste/img/bg-3.jpg"];
  var image = $(".img-fader");

  image.css("background-image","url("+images[count]+")");

  setInterval(function() {
    image.css("background-image", "url("+images[count++]+")");
    if(count == images.length)
    {
      count = 0;
    }
  }, 10000);

});
```

```css
.bg-secondary {
   background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.transition {
    transition: all 1.0s;
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Tema Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://weec-sistemas.000webhostapp.com/sistema-teste/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Estilo Customizado -->
  <link href="https://weec-sistemas.000webhostapp.com/sistema-teste/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Estilo Responsivo -->
  <link href="https://weec-sistemas.000webhostapp.com/sistema-teste/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  


<body class="img-fader transition">

  <div class="container">

    <form class="login-form bg-secondary" method="post" action="">
      <div class="login-wrap">
        <p class="login-img"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <input type="text" id="loginUsuario" name="loginUsuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuário" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <input type="password" id="senhaUsuario" name="senhaUsuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha">
        </div>
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="lembra-me"> Lembrar me
            <span class="pull-right"> <a href="#"> Esqueceu senha?</a></span>
          </label>
        <input type="submit" name="logar" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-disable-with="Login">
        <!-- <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Signup</button> -->
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>


  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script src="https://weec-sistemas.000webhostapp.com/sistema-teste/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

</body>
```

Comment: show, era isso que eu queria

Answer (score 0):

O problema está basicamente em que a classe que faz as transições (`.img-fader`) usando `fadeOut` e `fadeIn` está no `body`, logo, todo o conteúdo será afetado.

Uma solução é colocar o `form` fora da `div container` e aplicar a classe `.img-fader` à essa `div`. Com isso, o `form` não será afetado.

Também é necessário alterar o CSS do `form` para que ele fique centralizado na tela, e ajustar a altura `height` da `div container` para ocupar toda a tela.

Também substituir a classe `container` por `container-fluid`, que ocupará toda a largura da tela.

**O HTML ficará assim:**

> Não esqueça de apagar a class `img-fader` do `<body>`.

```
<div class="container-fluid img-fader">
</div>
<form class="login-form" method="post" action="https://weec-sistemas.000webhostapp.com/sistema-teste/login.php">
<div class="login-wrap">
  <p class="login-img"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <input type="text" id="loginUsuario" name="loginUsuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuário" autofocus>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <input type="password" id="senhaUsuario" name="senhaUsuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha">
  </div>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="lembra-me"> Lembrar me
      <span class="pull-right"> <a href="https://weec-sistemas.000webhostapp.com/sistema-teste/login.php#"> Esqueceu senha?</a></span>
    </label>
  <input type="submit" name="logar" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-disable-with="Login">
  <!-- <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Signup</button> -->
</div>
</form>
```

**Alterações no CSS**

Troque a class `.login-form` no seu CSS abaixo por este, irá centralizar na tela o formulário:

```
.login-form {
    max-width: 350px;
    background: #d5d7de, fixed;    
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Pra finalizar, inclua o código abaixo no seu arquivo `img-slider.js` logo no início do `$(document).ready(function(){`:

```
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
   $(".container-fluid").css("height",window.innerHeight+"px");
});
```

Ficando assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(window).on("load resize", function(){
      $(".container-fluid").css("height",window.innerHeight+"px");
   });

  var count = 0;
  var images = ["img/bg-1.jpg","img/bg-2.jpg","img/bg-3.jpg"];
  var image = $(".img-fader");

  image.css("background-image","url("+images[count]+")");

  setInterval(function(){
    image.fadeOut(500, function(){
      image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");
      image.fadeIn(500);
    });
    if(count == images.length)
    {
      count = 0;
    }
  },5000);

});
```

**[Veja funcionando aqui.](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/form.html)**